# How to make flutter mobile app associated to a django webapp?

Tags: python, html, django, rest, flutter

I have a **django webapp**, which is a repository for alumni. Users can sign up using the **extended user model** and fill-in multiple fields. Then there is a detail page for each user that shows their respective data. All this is built using **function based views**. This bit is fine. But I also want to make its corresponding **mobile apps** for android and ios hopefully in **flutter** otherwise **react native**. My question is, should I host this as it is, or there are some basic things that I already need in the code so I can make a REST API and connect mobile apps later? I don't really have any knowledge about mobile apps and connecting django's REST API? So please guide me in this regard.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There two ways to do it based in my knowldge :

1- using flutter web view in [packages website](https://pub.dev/packages?q=webview)  only pick the best pkg for you .

2-or using HTTPS req by [http pkg](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and make sure you have get and post in your backend like flask in paython or laraval php .

I hope I answred your question  :)

Comment: Actually I have the django website ready to deploy on the web. I want to make mobile app for it as well. Just like facebook has website as well as mobile app. What I know is that API is used for this purpose. But I want to know how to use the API and should I change my current django website code to work with the mobile app using the API?

Comment: Ya, you need to make API in django... BTW thanks :)

Comment: @AmeerHamza , they have api you can use it then learn flutter :) Good luck ameer

Comment: thanks.... by the way, do you have any experience in flutter. I mean what is its difficulty level  and how's the learning curve?

Comment: @AmeerHamza , im good at flutter , its very easy if you learn flutter actualy you  will save a lot of time , efort and money :) try it.